# Why can't I have updated states in function component (using hook)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have login function component with two inputs. It's controlled component so email and password are bound to state(user). Input is a component I use instead of input tag(refactoring input). I can change state user(email and password) with input values using handleInputChange event handler and I also can submit form using handleSubmit handler.

Everything was good until I tried to validate form using yup and catching errors. I declared errors state to save errors I got. I want to catch errors and show in "div className="alert""  and I want to post user to server when no error exists. I see the errors related to yup in validate() function, but when I change errors state(`setErrors([...er.errors])`) I find errors state empty (`console.log(errors.length)`).

Here is login component:

```
import axios from "axios";
import queryString from "query-string"
import { useEffect, useRef,useState } from "react";
import React from "react"
import {useLocation, useRouteMatch,useParams} from "react-router-dom"
import Input from "./input";
import * as yup from 'yup';
const Login = () => {
    useEffect(async()=>{
   
   
       
        console.log(errors)
    },[errors])

    var [user,setUser]=useState({email:'',password:''});
 var [errors,setErrors]=useState([])
 let schema=yup.object().shape({
    email:yup.string().email("ایمیل نامعتبر است").required("فیلد ایمیل الزامیست"),
    password:yup.string().min(8,"رمز عبور باید حداقل 8 رقم باشد")
})
const validate=async()=>{
    try  {
       const resultValidate=await schema.validate(user, { abortEarly: false })
       
    }
    catch(er){
       console.log(er.errors)
      setErrors([...er.errors])
     
       
    }
   }
  const  handleSubmit= async(e)=>{
      
e.preventDefault();
await validate();
console.log(errors.length)
if(errors.length===0){
    alert("X")
   const response= await axios.post("https://reqres.in/api/login",user)
   console.log(response)
 }
  }

const handleInputChange=async(e)=>{
 
  setUser({...user,[e.currentTarget.name]:e.currentTarget.value})


}
    return ( 
    <>
     <div id="login-box" className="col-md-12">
                        
            
                        {errors.length!==0  && (<div className="alert">
                            <ul>
                               {errors.map((element,item)=>{
                                    return(
                                    <>
                                     <li key={item}>
                                           {element}
                                    </li>
                                    </>
                                   )
                                })}
                            </ul>
                        </div>) }
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="login-form" className="form" action="" method="post">
                            <h3 className="text-center text-info">Login</h3>
                            <Input  onChange={handleInputChange} name="email" id="email" label="نام کاربری" value={user.email}/>
                            <Input  name="password" onChange={handleInputChange} id="password" value={user.password} label="رمز عبور"/>
                            
                         
                          
                            {/* <div id="register-link" className="text-right">
                                <a href="#" className="text-info">Register here</a>
                            </div> */}
                            <input type="submit"   className="btn btn-primary" value="ثبت"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
    </>
    );
}
 
export default Login;
```

and here is Input component:

```
import {Component} from "react"
class Input extends Component {
    render() { 
        return <>
        
   <div className="form-group">
   <label htmlFor="username" className="text-info">{this.props.label}</label><br/>
                                <input type="text" onChange={this.props.onChange} name={this.props.name} id={this.props.id} className="form-control" value={this.props.value} />
   </div>

        </>;
    }
}
 
export default Input;
```

I understood that setStates(in my component setErrors) are asynchronous and it's delayed. I tried using simple array variable (named errors) instead of state and hook, but guess what, it didn't rerender page when I changed the errors variable! Of course I can't see errors in page using this way.

I tried to resolve this using `useEffect()` and I decided to check validation errors and post in `useEffect` instead of `handleSubmit` handler:

```
 useEffect(async()=>{
   
    if(errors.length===0){

        const response= await axios.post("https://reqres.in/api/login",user)
        console.log(response)
      }
   
    console.log(errors)
}, [errors])
```

Now I see errors when inputs are invalid. When I type valid values, there are still same errors!
It looks like I can't have updated errors state and I just get previous errors even after I enter valid values! I try to not use class based component as I can. What shall I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return true if the input values are validated and false if not, from the `validate` function like this:

```
const validate = async () => {
try {
  const resultValidate = await schema.validate(user, { abortEarly: false });
  return true;
} catch (er) {
  console.log(er.errors);
  setErrors([...er.errors]);
  return false;
}
};
```

And now in the `handleSubmit` function you have to modify a bit:

```
 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const isValid = await validate();

 console.log(errors.length);

 if (isValid) {
  alert("X");
  const response= await axios.post("https://reqres.in/api/login",user)
  console.log(response)
  setErrors([]);  //so that the previous errors are removed
 }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The issue you face is that React state updates are ***asynchronously*** processed. This doesn't mean that the state update is `async` and can be waited for. The `errors` state you enqueue won't be available until the *next* render cycle.

```
const validate = async () => {
  try  {
    const resultValidate = await schema.validate(user, { abortEarly: false });       
  } catch(er) {
    console.log(er.errors);
    setErrors([...er.errors]); // (2) <-- state update enqueued
  }
}

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  await validate(); // (1) <-- validate called and awaited

  console.log(errors.length); // <-- (3) errors state from current render cycle

  if (errors.length === 0) {
    alert("X");
    const response = await axios.post("https://reqres.in/api/login", user);
    console.log(response);
  }
}
```

## Solution

I suggest returning an "errors" object from `validate` instead, you can enqueue any state updates later if you like.

```
const validate = async () => {
  const errors = [];
  try  {
    await schema.validate(user, { abortEarly: false });
  } catch(er) {
    console.log(er.errors);
    errors.push(...er.errors);
  }
  return errors;
}

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const errors = await validate();

  console.log(errors.length);

  if (!errors.length) {
    alert("X");
    const response = await axios.post("https://reqres.in/api/login", user);
    console.log(response);
  } else {
    setErrors(prevErrors => [...prevErrors, ...errors]);
  }
}
```